# Error in multiplying randomly generated matrices of huge sizes using C

Tags: c, matrix, optimization, matrix-multiplication

My primary aim is to demonstrate how virtualization differs from containerization by benchmarking a matrix multiplication algorithm in C and Java over various environments and draw up a suitable conclusion.

The reason I chose this algorithm was because matrix multiplication is a very frequently used algorithm in various Computer Science fields, since most of them deal with large sizes, I wish to optimize my code to be able to perform the action up to at least 2000x2000 matrix size so that the difference between both of these is apparent.

I use GCC on Linux and the default compiler for C in Code::Blocks on Windows (I do not know which version of GCC is uses).

The problem is that when I run the code on Windows, the compiler accepts sizes only up to 490x490 and dumps the core if I exceed the size. Linux manages to overcome this but cannot go beyond 590x590.

I initially thought that my device memory was the reason and asked a few of my friends with much better machines to run the same code, but the result was still the same.

FYI: I'm running a Pentium N3540 and 4GB of DDR3 RAM. My friends are running i7-8750H with 16GB DDR4 and another one with an i5-9300H with 8GB DDR4.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

int main()
{
    long i, j, k, m, n;
    printf("Enter the row dimension of the matrix: "); scanf("%ld", &m);
    printf("Enter the column dimension of the matrix: "); scanf("%ld", &n);
    long mat1[m][n], mat2[m][n], mat3[m][n];

    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            mat1[i][j] = (long)rand()%MAX;
            mat2[i][j] = (long)rand()%MAX;
            mat3[i][j] = 0;
        }

    printf("\n\nThe matrix 1 is: \n");
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", (int)mat1[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\nThe matrix 2 is: \n");
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", (int)mat2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
                mat3[i][j] += mat1[i][k] * mat2[k][j];

    printf("\n\nThe resultant matrix is: \n");
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", (int)mat3[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the heap and not  the stack. See malloc

Comment: For an explanation of your problem, see the name of this website :-)

Comment: Multiply `m` by `n` to get the  number of elements needed for each of `mat1`, `mat2` and `mat3`. Multiply by `3` to get the the total number of elements for all three matrices. Multiply by `sizeof(long) ` (which is 4 or 8) to get the size in bytes needed for all your arrays. Compared that size with the standard size of the Stack on your system (8 MiB on Linux, 1 MiB on Windows). That should help you understand what the problem is.

Comment: Instead of `printf("%d\t", (int)mat3[i][j]);`, use `printf("%ld\t", mat3[i][j]);`

Comment: Should `mat1[i][j]` have the values 0 to `MAX` or 0 to `MAX-1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
long mat1[m][n], mat2[m][n], mat3[m][n];
```

you create an object (aka a variable) with automatic storage duration. That means that the object is automatically created once the function is executed and automatically destroyed when the function exits.

The C standard does not describe how this shall be done. That is left to the system implementing the standard. The most common way is to use what is called a stack. It's a memory area that is pre-allocated for your program. Whenever your program calls functions any variables defined inside the function can be placed on that stack. This allows for very simple and fast allocation of memory for such variables.

However, it has one drawback - the stack has a limited (and rather small) size. So if a function uses huge variables, you may run out of stack memory. Unfortunately, most systems doesn't detect that until it's too late.

The simple rule to avoid this is: Do not define huge variables with automatic storage duration (aka huge function local variables).

So for your specific example you should replace:

```
long mat1[m][n]
```

with

```
long (*mat1)[n] = malloc(m * sizeof *mat1); // This defines mat1 as a pointer
if (mat1 == NULL)                           // to an array of n longs and
{                                           // allocate memory of m such arrays.
    // Out of memory                        // In other words:
    exit(1);                                // A m by n matrix of long
}

// From here on you can use mat1 as a 2D matrix
// example:
mat1[4][9] = 42;

...

// Once you are done using mat1, you need to free the memory. Like:
free(mat1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for specifying this! I never considered the possibility of using dynamic memory allocation (though I feel like I shouldn't have missed this point).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from [@EdHeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892256/ed-heal) 's suggestion of using `malloc()` , you may also simply use `static` to make your variable global, forcing it to be placed outside the *stack* in the *heap* - Assuming you dont mind an immutable matrice.

Since anyways here you must make arrays of *variable length*, `malloc()` is naturally suited to your use-case.

The stack is for small things; the heap for large things - and in your own words, these are matrices of "*huge sizes*" :)

As a sidenote to those more experienced in C programming - **Why don't more C textbooks teach about stack-heap theory and size limitations of non-`malloc()`ed `auto` variables ?** *Why must every newb learn by falling flat on their face and being told of this on S.O ?*